# Nested SOQL with 4 objects

Tags: soql

I am trying to have one SOQL query that builds a JSON for API work that I am pushing. I keep getting the error

```
From OpportunityLineItems) FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :opp.Id)
                                ^
ERROR at Row:2:Column:320
Didn't understand relationship 'Opportunity' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to
 use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. 
Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

I am not sure if I am just blind but I am struggling to see where my error on this is for the AT var?

```apex
public with sharing class UpsertNewOpportunity{
    public static void UpsertNewOpportunity(Opportunity opp) {
        System.debug('Closed Won - ' + opp.Id);
        string oppQuery = 'SELECT SAP_Quote_CardCode__c, Account.Name, Primary_Contact__r.SAP_Contact_ID__c, Sales_Employee_Code__c, Owner.User_Code__c, Discount__c, Shipping_Type_Code__c, Shipping_Cost__c, Ship_To__c, Bill_to__c, Terms__c, (Select ProductCode, Description, Quantity, Discount, UnitPrice From OpportunityLineItems) FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = \'' + opp.Id + '\'';
        string contactQuery = 'SELECT Primary__c, Name, FirstName, LastName, MailingAddress, Position__c, Title, SAP_Contact_ID__c, Email, Phone, OtherPhone, MobilePhone FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = \'' + opp.AccountId + '\'';
        string addressQuery = 'SELECT Name, Address__c, Address_2__c, Address_3__c, Billing__c, Shipping__c, City__c, State__c, Zip_Code__c, Building_Floor_Room__c, Country__c, Ship_to_Name__c, Phone__c, Email_address__c FROM Address__c WHERE Account__c = \'' + opp.AccountId + '\'';
        //account level fields - Email, OtherPhone
        string accountQuery = 'SELECT Name, Corp_Name__c, Website, Status__c, SAP_Type__c, Phone, Price_List__c, Channel__c, Series__c, Owner.User_Code__c, Discount__c, Parent__c, Terms__c, (SELECT SAP_Quote_CardCode__c, Account.Name, Primary_Contact__r.SAP_Contact_ID__c, Sales_Employee_Code__c, Owner.User_Code__c, Discount__c, Shipping_Type_Code__c, Shipping_Cost__c, Ship_To__c, Bill_to__c, Terms__c, (Select ProductCode, Description, Quantity, Discount, UnitPrice From OpportunityLineItems) FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = \'' + opp.Id + '\'), (SELECT Primary__c, Name, FirstName, LastName, MailingAddress, Position__c, Title, SAP_Contact_ID__c, Email, Phone, OtherPhone, MobilePhone FROM Contact), (SELECT Name, Address__c, Address_2__c, Address_3__c, Billing__c, Shipping__c, City__c, State__c, Zip_Code__c, Building_Floor_Room__c, Country__c, Ship_to_Name__c, Phone__c, Email_address__c FROM Address__c) FROM Account WHERE AccountId = \'' + opp.AccountId + '\'';

        Account at = [SELECT Name, Corp_Name__c, Website, Status__c, SAP_Type__c, Phone, Price_List__c, Channel__c, Series__c, Owner.User_Code__c, Discount__c, Parent__c, Terms__c, 
        (SELECT SAP_Quote_CardCode__c, Account.Name, Primary_Contact__r.SAP_Contact_ID__c, Sales_Employee_Code__c, Owner.User_Code__c, Discount__c, Shipping_Type_Code__c, Shipping_Cost__c, Ship_To__c, Bill_to__c, Terms__c, 
        (Select ProductCode, Description, Quantity, Discount, UnitPrice From OpportunityLineItems) FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :opp.Id),
        (SELECT Primary__c, Name, FirstName, LastName, MailingAddress, Position__c, Title, SAP_Contact_ID__c, Email, Phone, OtherPhone, MobilePhone FROM Contact),
        (SELECT Name, Address__c, Address_2__c, Address_3__c, Billing__c, Shipping__c, City__c, State__c, Zip_Code__c, Building_Floor_Room__c, Country__c, Ship_to_Name__c, Phone__c, Email_address__c FROM Address__c)
        FROM Account WHERE AccountId = :opp.AccountId ];
        
        Opportunity oppResult = Database.query(oppQuery);
        List<Contact> contacts = Database.query(contactQuery);
        List<Address__c> addresses = Database.query(addressQuery);
        Account a = Database.query(accountQuery);
        System.debug(a);
        System.debug(a.Contacts);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Broken down and formatted in a more readable way with less important parts stripped out, what you have is

```
SELECT
    <Account fields>,
    (SELECT
        <Opportunity fields>,
        (SELECT
            <OpportunityLineItem fields>
        )
        FROM
            Opportunity
    ),
    (SELECT
        <Contact fields>
    ),
    (SELECT
        <Address__c fields>
    )
FROM
    Account
WHERE
    <some filter>
```

The error you're seeing is that `FROM Opportunity` bit. Since this is a parent-child subquery, you need to use the child relationship name (`Opportunities`).

Beyond that though, your query has another issue. We are only allowed to go 1 level down in parent-child queries, so your additional nested parent-child subquery for `OpportunityLineItem` is *not syntactically valid*.

You cannot do what you are looking to do in a single query. You're going to need to break the query for `OpportunityLineItem` out into a separate query and then do some processing in Apex (using some classes to aid you in serializing) to stitch everything together into the JSON that you're looking for.

Comment: That stitching is going to have to be done using `Map<String, Object>` since SObjects do not allow relationship field (lists) to be written to... it's a PITA.